# Non-mutating version of std::map

Tags: c++, stl

I'm looking for best practices for tweaking the behavior of containers. stl containers aren't well suited for inheritance, writing 50 pass-through methods isn't ideal either. Here is the specific example I'm dealing with today.

Calling operator[](T t) on std::map will insert an entry the _first isn't found.

```
std::map<int,string> m;
string s = m[10]; // will insert empty string into the map
```

So I ended up calling something like this.

```
string mapfind(int id, const map<int, string>& m)
{
     auto entry = m.find(id);
     if(entry != m.end())
     {
        return *entry;     
     } else {
        return "not found";
     }
};
```

This is also terrible since external function needs to know to be called. How can I modify the container to use a default value rather than mutating state?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with making  function like that and using it everywhere. Just use std::map::find in place where you need it. What are the chances you want "not found" and string for life? two and three line "extension" or "utility" methods really do me no good when they are only replacing one or two lines...Alternatively, you can use map::at, as suggested by one of the answers.

Comment: At first I didn't really care, but I'm exposing an interface and I want all my getters to be const functions.

Comment: C++ doesn't have Extension Methods as C#, you may still add free functions though (`template <typename Key, typename Value> Value get_or_default(const std::map<Key,Value>&, const non_deducible_t<Key>&, const non_deducible_t<Value>& defaultValue)`).

Answer (score 3):

You could simply call [`std::map::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at). It will throw if the element isn't in the map:

```
string s = m.at(10); // throws
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is not the behavior I'm looking for. I want it to actually return a specific default and for the tree to not mutate.